# Proof related to direct sum and subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I did the following exercise: If $U_1, U_2, W$ are subspaces of $V$ with the property $V = U_1 \oplus W = U_2 \oplus W$ then $U_1 = U_2$.

My proof: Assume $u_1 \in U_1 \subset V$. Then $u_1 \in U_2 \oplus W = V$. Then $u_1 = u_2 + w$. Also $u_1 = u_1 + 0 \in U_2 \oplus W$. By uniqueness of direct sum it follows that $w=0$ and $u_1=u_2 \in U_2$. Similarly for the other inclusion.

Is this correct?

Comment: Let $V = \mathbb R^2$, $W = \langle (1, 0) \rangle$, $U_1 = \langle (1, 1) \rangle$ and $U_2 = \langle (1, -1) \rangle$, where the notation $\langle \ldots \rangle$ means the subspace generated by $\ldots$. (What is "uniqueness of direct sum"?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "uniqueness property" of the direct sum is the following:
If $V = W \oplus U$ and $w + u = w' + u'$ with $u,u'\in U$, $w,w'\in W$, then $w = w'$ and $u = u'$.

You wrongly applied this property to $u_1 + 0 = u_2 + w$.
Because of $V = U_1 \oplus W = U_2 \oplus W$ and $0,w\in W$ you would either need $u_1,u_2\in U_1$ or $u_1,u_2\in U_2$. But you only know $u_1\in U_1$ and $u_2\in U_2$, which is not enough.

In fact, the statement you are trying to prove is wrong. A counterexample is provided in the comment of Tunococ:

Let $F$ be a field, $V = F^2$, $W = \langle (1,0)\rangle$, $U_1 = \langle(1,1)\rangle$ and $U_2 = \langle(1,-1)\rangle$. Then $V = W\oplus U_1 = W\oplus U_2$, but $U_1\neq U_2$.